# mouse event not occuring on hover of link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this codepen here: https://codepen.io/albicant__/pen/LYYLQPj

```
link.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
bg.style.backgroundImage = `url(${this.dataset.bg})`;
```

I'm trying to make the image call into a defined div when you hover on a link and stay there until the next link is hovered on and another image is called. It should load as a blank ideally.

It's essentially a modification of this: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-quick-full-screen-background-hover-effect--cms-33656?_ga=2.124226435.842080093.1572567200-2138059684.1569626832

I also can't seem to preload the images when I do this on my own live server... works just about okay in codepen though?

But I feel like i've gone wrong in the syntax somewhere? 
Any feedback would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What happens on your server? Does the hover just not work (display the images)?

Comment: If that's the case, try to move your `script` section below your body & see what happens. `Codepen imports the JS at the bottom of your body` [Codepen import order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437419/put-codepen-javascript-in-head-instead-of-body) so if you're importing the code in your head & `Codepen` is importing after the body, that's the difference. Just modify your order.

Comment: @EGC It's now calling yes (thank you!!)- but there isn't a smooth transition in the changes between various mouse events in moz (only jerky in the intial one in chrome); it's quite jerky and has a fair delay.. I think it's because it's not preloading images as it's at the bottom of the footer?

Adding webkit and moz prefaces don't seem to help with smoothing out the element(s)

Is there anything i can do to fix this, or is this something I'll have to live with?